# What lookups can a index on 1+ columns help in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If I make an index on 2 decimal columns `col1`, `col2`, what kind of lookups have I made faster?

Intuitively, it can satisfy **exact matches** on both columns and works on a `where col1...` and doesnt work at all for `where col2 ...`. And also **range searches** on `col1` but not on `col2`; and range searches on `col2` given `col1`.

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fater for condition

```
where col1=(something) and  col2=(something)
```

or for just `where col1=(something)`

It **will not** use this index for

```
where col2=(something) and  col1=(something)
```

For Range searches, it will be faster only for col1, as col1 is in the left most in the index

Comment: Sorry for the sudden change, but how will it perform for range searches too?